# how to get current time from given timezone name in java?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime, simpledateformat

I want to get current time from given timezone that can be like "IST" or "Indian Standard Time" etc.
I am not able get time when input is "Indian Standard Time" or "Coordinated Universal Time". it works only for "IST" or "UTC" or "EST" etc.
i have tried with Joda-Time and SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
Date date = new Date();
sd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
System.out.println(sd.format(date));



DateTime now = new DateTime();
//DateTimeZone LDateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTimeZone LDateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "IST" );   //deprecated
System.out.println( "Joda-Time zone: " + now.toDateTime( LDateTimeZone ) );
```

Is there any way to handle both the inputs?

Comment: Always use the full IANA tz database name - `Asia/Kolkata`.  Abbreviations are not unique (India/Israel/Ireland?) and humanized names are language/locale specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot advise more strongly against using the legacy `java.util.Date`.  You should use the appropriate `java.time` class instead.

In `java.time.ZonedDateTime`, you can create a time zone alias map and populate it as you please.  It's not pretty, but it works.

```
Map<String, String> aliasMap = new HashMap<>();
aliasMap.put("IST", "Asia/Calcutta");
aliasMap.put("Indian Standard Time", "Asia/Calcutta");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Indian Standard Time", aliasMap));
```

Comment: No doubt its a good approach to handle this kind of scenario but in my case i need for all the timezone. It will be difficult for me to hard code all timezone available.

Comment: [Here](http://www.javadb.com/list-possible-timezones-or-zoneids-in-java/) is the list of all of the `ZoneId`s supported natively by Java.  This should help you to create the alias map that you need.

Comment: A better reference is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  There are a few in Java not on that list, but those should be considered deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do like this using joda

```
TimeZone timezone;
timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Indian Standard Time");
DateTime dt = new DateTime(new Date());
DateTimeZone dtZone = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(timezone);
DateTime afterSetTimezone = dt.withZone(dtZone);
Date date = afterSetTimezone.toLocalDateTime().toDate();
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: Sorry TimeZone.getTimeZone("") function supports only short names like IST or UTC as i have attached code with my question. it do not work for TimeZone.getTimeZone("Indian Standard Time").